# How to conditionally format a row in Excel VBA based on if first cell is empty?

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is very simple, I just don't have much VBA / Excel experience to know how to do it.
I am working on a macro to do a few different things, I'm just stuck on this part.

What I want to do is go through all of my rows, and if the first cell in the row is empty, I want to select the entire row and UnMerge it. I know that if the first cell is empty, that row contains merged cells that I want unmerged.

I know that these two lines below will select row 2 and Unmerge it, but I need a way to loop through my data and find and unmerge the rows automatically, because the row numbers wont be the same every time.

```
Rows("2:2").Select

Selection.UnMerge
```

I want to do something like this:

```
For (each row) {
   if (the first cell is empty) {
       UnMerge all cells in that row;
   }
}
```

I just don't know how to do that in VBA syntax.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
Sub UnmergeRows()

    Dim R       As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")           ' change tab name as required
        ' "B" should be the longest column in the worksheet
        For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(R, 1)) Then .Rows(R).MergeCells = False
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that's close, but it doesn't seem to be unmerging the row yet. 

For a little more context, what I want to do is if the first cell (in column A) is empty, then I want to select that entire row, and unmerge all the cells in that entire row. I want to check this for all the rows of my data

Comment: The problem must be that the first cell isn't blank. Try replacing `IsEmpty(.Cells(R, 1))` with `Len(Trim(.Cells(R, 1).Value)) = 0`. Are there merged cells in the rows where the first cell isn't blank?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! I guess it must not be blank, although there is no text or anything in the first cell. Weird. I appreciate the help!